# Changing the index variable in a recursion relation

Tags: recursion

Can I change 
$$
x_{n+2} = 14x_{n+1} - 49x_n + n7^n\\
n>=0\\
x_0 = 1\\
x_2=14
$$
to
$$
x_{n} = 14x_{n-1} - 49x_{n-2} + n7^n\\
n>=2\\
x_0 = 1\\
x_2=14
$$

And it's same? I need to find solutions of recursive equations, but have no idea how do it when have 
$$
x_{n+2} =...
$$
not 
$$
a_n =...
$$
like in others exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it but notice that when you changes $x_n$ to $x_{n-2}$ in the second term you should have done the same to $n\cdot 7^n$ so the recursion looks like
$$x_n=14x_{n-1}-49x_{n-2}+(n-2)\cdot 7^{n-2}.$$